# IOS Resize CCSprite is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I know this is a very stupid question, but I'm trying to resize and its not refecting.

```
 CCSprite * title;
 title = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"flow.png"];
 [title setScaleX:0.55f];
 [title setScaleY:0.55f];
```

Comment: Do you mean that you see exactly the same thing as if you were not setting the scale to (0.55,0.55)? If so, it has to be changed somewhere else too.

Answer (score 0):

**Resize Sprite flollowing code**

```
-(void)Spriteresize:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height
{
    sprite.scaleX = width / sprite.contentSize.width;
    sprite.scaleY = height / sprite.contentSize.height;
}
```

**Use this method as below**

```
[self Spriteresize:title toWidth:300 toHeight:200];
```